# accept() returns same socket descriptor numbers

Tags: c, linux, sockets, process, fork

As the argument of `accept()` for new client socket, 
the listener socket is in shared memory area and is shared by all forked server processes.

but each server processesaccept()`returns the same socket descriptor after`accept()` is called by all different forked processes.

Does the `fork()` also makes separate area for socket descriptors and each forked process
manage the area separately? 
Is that why they produce duplicate socket descriptors?

I intended to use `select()` to detect changes on all socket descriptors,
but because they produce all same descriptors, I couldn't make it out..

Comment: This setup sounds strange, you are calling `accept()` on the same socket from multiple servers that you've `fork()`ed? Eh? Normally, you have a single server calling `accept()` on the socket, and `fork()` a separate process to handle the client socket... <puzzled/>

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061961/unix-accept-function-returns-the-same-file-descriptor-twice

Comment: @MeNa: The linked question refers to threads not processes.

Comment: @alk You right... this is about processes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915144/c-same-file-descriptors-of-all-client-connections-client-server-programming

Comment: The listening socket is shared because it was a open file descriptor when you forked, not because you are using shared memory (which isn't required). Each established new connection exists only in one process, and can't be accessed from the others (that were forked before the `accept`)

Comment: Douglas, it was really useful answer. Then even if I had different number of socket descriptor from each other processes, they also can`t be accessed from each other processes, right?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, socket descriptors' (as well as file descriptors) values are managed on a per-process base.

Comment: Then all file descriptors are also managed by per process base? Then the shared file descriptors are the file descriptors that were created before forking?

Comment: Just for completeness... it's not true that inheriting over fork is the *only* way to share a file descriptor with another process. There is also file descriptor passing. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358684/can-i-share-a-file-descriptor-to-another-process-on-linux-or-are-they-local-to-t

Comment: Wumpus! If I could see your answer a bit earlier, That would have changed a lot for the work I`m doing. Thanks anyway really much.